# Is it bad form to pass an empty query string to a URL?

Tags: html, url, get, request, query-string

If I have a URL on a site that optionally takes parameters:

```
http://example.com/process?foo=bar&baz=quux
```

Is it bad form to pass it an empty query string:

```
http://example.com/process?
```

Instead of this:

```
http://example.com/process
```

?

Comment: In terms of bad form there are _plenty_ of worse offenses on the web than passing an empty query string.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on each HTTP server's implementation. I'm sure most will just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

IMO No it is not bad form.  Maybe it isn't ideal, but I don't think it is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

well definitely it is unnecessary, but if you have to spend your valuable time on fixing this one thing instead of doing something that really affects user's experience than I would say it is not worth.. wasting time imo :)

Comment: i asked because my code looks prettier like this: `url = '%s?%s' % (base_url, urllib.urlencode(params))` instead of like this: `if params: url = '%s?%s' % (base_url, urllib.urlencode(params)); else: url = base_url`. is that a valid enough reason? =P

Answer (score 0):

don't worry. no problem to transmit the additional ? character, it's kind of an overhead, doesnt' matter at all though